# Screenshot paste only works in some apps, not in Google Chrome

Tags: high-sierra, google-chrome, copy-paste

I used to love <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> for pasting screen grabs. But now it doesn't work in Chrome.

In Stickies and Text Edit it doesn't work and gives the Apple error sound.

The pasting Works fine in Discord, Skype and Firefox.

I'm using macOS High Sierra 10.13.4, copy paste image doesn't work in Safari either.

This is a real productivity killer.

Comment: Let's have a little more information, please. What version of macOS are you running? What version of Chrome? How many applications have you tried the key command in and for what result? What have you tried to fix the problem?

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior in Notes. I can see that the clipboard has an image in it, but trying to paste it gives an error sound. A workaround is to drop the ctrl from the key-combo and you'll get an image on your desktop then you can just drag that wherever you want an image.

Comment: What version of macOS High Sierra are you using?

Comment: Can't replicate. macOS 10.13.4, screen grab copied to clipboard via cmd-shift-ctrl-4 can be pasted from/to any app I am testing (including Chrome).

Comment: Related? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317361/cannot-paste-images-from-clipboard-to-facebook-in-safari-unlike-google-chrome/317609#317609

Comment: I'm using 10.13.4, copy paste image doesn't work in safari either

Comment: Can you edit your question to include what (if anything) you've already tried?

Comment: I've tried enough apps to know there is a bug, I also just upgrade my OS and had the same issue as el capitan

Comment: @dr.nixon depends where you are trying to paste it. You can paste into a Facebook status, for example, but not into a Stack Overflow reply.

Comment: Works for me in Chrome, Stickies, TextEdit, Safari (composing a Facebook status update). What does _Clipboard Viewer.app_ or _Finder/Edit/Show Clipboard_ show you?

Comment: @MattSephton it shows the correct image

Comment: Does it work if you login as a Guest user?

Comment: @MattSephton yes it does!

Comment: Then it's something in your own user account changing the behaviour. Are you using any sort of clipboard manager?

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? `shift+control+command+4` allows you to capture something from the screen onto the clipboard by dragging over the area you want to capture.  Then `Control+V` will paste what you've captured to wherever you need to (as long as where you're pasting supports pasting images)  Are you having trouble capturing or pasting what you've captured?

Comment: pasting is the issue

Comment: In what situation are you pasting into Safari for example?

Comment: gmail paste image from clipboard

Comment: Can you try something, copy an image to the clipboard with `shift+command+control+4`, then try to paste into gmail in Safari.  If it fails to work, immediately try the same into gmail in Firefox without copying again.  I'm trying to understand if the image is actually on the clipboard when pasting to Safari

Comment: There's an easier way actually, switch to Finder and click Edit > Show Clipboard

Comment: that works, already discussed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75927/discussion-between-conorgriffin-and-superuberduper).

Comment: Can you execute this and post the output?
`plutil -p ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginitems.plist`

Comment: Did you try that? Or fix it somehow?

Comment: I did try it, it was posted in the chat..

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this kind of behaviour with other functionality, try the following command in Terminal (may require sudo)

Change directory to "/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/"

`cd /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/`

`./lsregister -kill -seed`

**OR**

`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -seed`

This rebuilds the launch services database, sometimes corruption in this can cause weird behaviour

---

**EDIT:**
Since the above didn't help let's try something else.  When you use <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> to copy a section of the screen to the clipboard you can view the clipboard contents.
To do so, switch to Finder and click Edit > Show Clipboard to show the contents of the clipboard.  You should see something like this window pop up that says "Clipboard" at the top and has a description of the clipboard contents in the bottom-left corner.  Do you get the same thing?

[image: clipboard]

Comment: thx, but I get lsregister: command not found

Comment: Sorry, I had it on my path from before :)
Updated the instructions

Comment: no luck with either im afraid

Comment: Do you mean it didn't help or you couldn't execute `lsregister`?

Comment: it didnt help unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Since replicating this problem on other systems running macOS High Sierra 10.13.4 has proven difficult, it's probably worth starting with some basics to see if we can resolve or narrow down the problem.

Your question doesn't actually state what you've already tried (if anything) to resolve this, so perhaps you could start by booting into Safe Mode to see if that makes any difference.

**Boot into Safe Mode**

Follow these steps to boot your Mac into Safe Mode:

1. Fully shut down your Mac
2. Restart your Mac
3. Immediately press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and **keep it down**
4. Let go of the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when you see the login window (NOTE: If you have FileVault enabled you may need to log in twice).
5. Take a note of what happens (i.e. does <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> work for pasting screen grabs?)
6. Exit Safe Mode by restarting your Mac as normal
7. Test again

Once you've booted into Safe Mode, let me know how you went and we'll go from there.

**Reset NVRAM**

Okay, since booting into Safe Mode made no difference, we should now try resetting the NVRAM. Since you haven't specified the model of Mac you're using, refer to Apple's [How to reset NVRAM or PRAM on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204063) page.

**[EDIT] - Known bug in Google Chrome**

Not really an answer - at least not the one you're looking for - but I decided to check https://bugs.chromium.org to see if this was a known issue. It appears a number of issues relating to copy and paste (and the clipboard generally) in Chrome for macOS have been raised by users. In some cases the issues affect only text, while in others images and text. Some of the reported issues affect Windows, Linux, etc.

Below are some examples:

- [Issue 814346](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=814346)
- [Issue 818167](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=818167)
- [Issue 800742](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=800742)
- [Issue 830251](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=830251)
- [Issue 830149](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=830149)
- [Issue 827189](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=827189)

It's hard to know whether any of these are related to your issue or not, especially since not everyone can reproduce it, but it could also be an intermittent bug or combination of bugs.

Comment: doing it now thx

Comment: no luck with that, trying the other answer

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer.

Comment: thx i have a 2015 MBP 13""

Comment: no luck with that either

Comment: thx for the update