# Cannot paste images from clipboard to Facebook in Safari unlike Google Chrome

Tags: macos, safari, google-chrome, graphics, copy-paste

I have problems pasting images from clipboard to Facebook in Safari.

I have recently uninstalled Google Chrome and started using Safari since Chrome uses tons of energy and memory. I liked it but I had to reinstall Chrome since the Safari clipboard is very limited.

For example in Google Chrome I can copy and paste easily pictures from Tumblr to Facebook, using shortcuts or looking for the option with the Magic Mouse. In Safari this does not work in any possible way, I tried "cmd + v" to paste an image I have copied before which I expect should work, but does not. Yes, in Safari I cannot paste any image!

I have macOS High Sierra 10.13.3 MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports)

Do I need to reinstall Chrome in order to be able to paste images in Facebook?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Does Safari works as well as chrome? Or do I need to reinstall chrome in order to be able to paste images in facebook?

Comment: This would appear to be a Facebook issue and how the handle the clipboard API.  I don't see anything here for us to fix/address.

Comment: How exactly are you doing the Copy to clipboard? Also see my answer.

Comment: Copy image. Chrome pastes then the image not the url. But safari pastes text url instead of the picture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bug was fixed in [Safari Technology Preview 51](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/)—basically early access to the next version of Safari—where you can paste images into Facebook there just like in Chrome. Hopefully that is enough to solve your problem! Video: https://youtu.be/ITyIWMyoyRk

Though the feature was broken in some later Safari Technology Preview builds, it was fixed for the public release of Safari 11.1 included in macOS 10.13.4 which was released on 29th March 2018.

—original answer—

If I do this:

1. Right/context click on a Tumblr image
2. Choose "Copy Image Address"

Then both browsers paste the image URL into Facebook. No problems.

If I do this:

1. Right/context click on a Tumblr image
2. Choose "Copy Image"

Then I get slightly different behaviour in browsers when pasting into Facebook. Chrome pastes the URL of the image, Safari posts the URL of the post/page containing the image. That's because Safari is much more thorough with what it copies to the clipboard in this instance, as it includes more alternate representations than Chrome. However both browsers still show an image in Facebook. No problems.

> As an aside, you can inspect what is on the clipboard using *Finder > Edit > Show Clipboard*, which shows the default format. For a more in-depth look, use [Apple's Clipboard Viewer](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Auxiliary_Tools_for_Xcode_7/Auxiliary_Tools_for_Xcode_7.dmg) which shows extended information about the different representations stored on the clipboard.

So I'm thinking that you are doing the Copy to clipboard in a different way? Maybe you can try using one of the above copy methods?

Comment: I'm choosing Copy Image which adds the image itself to the clipboard, I can paste the image in a graph editor, etc.. I am not interested in the URL containing the image, because sometimes I want to paste multiple tumblr images in a unique single fb post, which would be impossible with the URL previews. But I don't want to download each image, just pasting them with cmd+v. Chrome has this behavior and it is rare than there arent other options on macOS itself.

Comment: I tested the [Safari Technology Preview](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/)—basically early access to the next version of Safari—and you can paste images into Facebook there. Hopefully that is enough to solve your problem!

Comment: this solves the problem, it works even better than chrome thank you

Comment: I still have to use chrome since in safari tech i cannot use the safari extensions

Comment: @GastónBurrull you should be able to use extensions, but you'll need to add them again - it won't use those installed in regular Safari. Unless something has changed recently? I'll look into it.

Comment: solved, I have to use the safari gallery extensions instead of the usual way to install extensions, since that way open sometimes safari instead of stp

Comment: @GastónBurrull you should be able to right click + option "open with" to choose Safari TP. Or drag & drop extension onto it, rather than double-clicking the extension.

Comment: it doesn't work anymore, safari tech preview is not pasting images

Comment: Did your Safari Tech Preview update? Hopefully you can go back to a previous version?

Comment: I have no idea, just stop working as before and have some minor new bugs

Comment: What does it say in the About box?

Comment: Release 52 (Safari 11.2, WebKit 13606.1.9.3.1)

Comment: Have you tried to remove STP and install the older version?

Comment: where can I find it?, your link download version 52

Comment: https://webkit.org/downloads/ you can also go back through the WebKit archive, to find the version that breaks it, report the bug and help all users

Comment: I really cannot find where are the previous versions of webkit. I tried searching the sitemap again and again

Comment: Try the Safari 11.1 beta

Comment: that does not work in high sierra 10.13.3

Comment: I know that Safari Technology Preview 51 works but i cant find it

Comment: Yay! Safari 11.1 fixes this in macOS 10.13.4

Comment: I have this problem in Safari 15 and Safari 16