# Download link for older Safari Technology Preview version 51

Tags: safari, copy-paste

As was answered in this question, [Cannot paste images from clipboard to Facebook in Safari unlike Google Chrome](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317361/cannot-paste-images-from-clipboard-to-facebook-in-safari-unlike-google-chrome/317609?noredirect=1#comment405468_317609), Safari Technology Preview 51 has the attribute to copy and paste Facebook and Tumblr images. Apple has recently upgraded Safari Technology Preview to release 52 and it has more Facebook related bugs than release 51. It has also lost that attribute.

Where can I download Safari Technology Preview version 51?

Comment: Tech previews are considered beta software.  Please be sure to follow the tips in [this post](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/2181/88313) in your question.

Comment: Do you run Time Machine? The previous version might be there...

Comment: no, I dont have it @SteveChambers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no official way to download older releases of Safari Technology Preview.

Answer (score 20):

Use the Wayback Machine:
https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://developer.apple.com/safari/download/

Once you find the download page of the version you'd like to download, strip Wayback Machine's URL prefix, and download it directly from Apple's servers.

Comment: Accept this answer as this can be a help to everyone as it was to me!

Comment: Thanks! This was a lifesaver. For version 125 specifically, wayback machine on may 27 does the trick. With the following being the download link for Safari Technology Preview 125 for Catalina: https://web.archive.org/web/20210527075420/https://secure-appldnld.apple.com/STP/071-44527-20210526-93430244-0334-4fae-878d-56502a656003/SafariTechnologyPreview.dmg

Comment: This is the one.